# What is a Turtle Object?

Tags: python, python-turtle

The book i'm reading is called Think Python 2. The author keeps on mentioning objects but i still do not understand what they actually are.... The code reads as follows

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)
turtle.mainloop()
```

"The turtle module (with a lowercase ’t’) provides a function called Turtle (with an uppercase ’T’) that creates a Turtle object."

So what this means is that the module defined the function Turtle, and when it was defined it created a function object 'Turtle'?

"which we assign to a variable named bob. Printing bob displays something like

```
turtle.Turtle object at 0xb7bfbf4c
```

This means that bob refers to an object with type Turtle as defined in module turtle."

I can't understand what is he doing atm... Is he assigning the return value of Turtle()function to a variable called Bob?
And why is bob's type Turtle? Isn't it type function? As when you define a function it creates a function object in this case "Turtle" of type "Function"...

I'm kinda messed up. What am i missing?

Comment: This question can be improved by improving your title. The first suggestion that comes to mind is _What is a Turtle object?_

Comment: `Turtle()` creates an object; a representation of data. 'mainLoop` is a method of `Turtle` objects.

Comment: I agree that it's a little confusing with all these turtles scampering around. When you call the `turtle.Turtle()` function it returns a `Turtle` object, which is distinct from the `turtle.Turtle()` function object that created it. The `Turtle` object is used to draw stuff. It holds some data (eg its current position and colour), and it also has some functions attached to it (functions attached to objects are often called _methods_), you can call those functions to make the `Turtle` object do stuff, like move or draw. Does that help?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, it indeed helped. Still, i don't understand why does calling a Function Turtle() returns an object. If i make a function def Tom(): print("hi") And i say x =Tom() , Am i creating an object of type Tom?

Comment: No. That function doesn't have an explicit `return` statement, but every Python function _must_ return something. If you don't  provide a `return` statement your function will return `None`, which is a special object of type `NoneType`. :) So `x =Tom()` binds the name `x` to the `None` object. The `Tom` function doesn't actually _create_ the `None` object: it's already built-in to the interpreter.

Comment: TBH, I simplified things a bit in my first comment. Technically, `turtle.Turtle` _isn't_ a function: it's a class. But like a function, a class is callable. When you call a class, its `__new__` method is invoked to create a class instance object. Then the instance is passed to the class's `__init__` method to initialize it, and then the  instance is returned to the caller. Please see [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) in the Python tutorial. Some of that info may not make much sense at this stage, so skim over that & try to understand the bits that you can. :)

Comment: @TomasSandacz You need to lookup what a constructor is. They're a special kind of function that create and return an object when called.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you very much guys :) So Turtle() is a class, is a constructor, than it can be called just as functions can. When we call a class it then returns  an object of that class, in this case an object of type Turtle which will allow us to acces methods and functions inside the Turtle  class? :)

Comment: @TomasSandacz You've got it!

Answer (score 1):

```
# Import the turtle module
import turtle
# Create a variable named bob, assign it a Turtle object which comes from the turtle module
bob = turtle.Turtle()
# Print out the variable bob
print(bob)
# Call a method named mainloop from the turtle package
turtle.mainloop()
```

Read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) for more about what a module is.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean when you say it assign it a Turtle object? Isn't it assigning a function return value? He is calling the function Turtle() from the turtle module, isn't he?

Comment: `turtle.Turtle()` creates a new Turtle object. You then assign that object to the variable `bob`. He is calling the *constructor* `Turtle` which returns a new instance of the Turtle object.

Comment: Sorry that's too specific language for me.

Comment: Great! Now it's time to learn what those words mean and continue reading the book :)

Comment: Technically, `turtle.mainloop()` doesn't "Call a method named mainloop ..." as it's not a *method*, there's no object instance, nor class here -- just a package.  Invoked this way, `turtle.mainloop()` is a *function* from the turtle package that in turn invokes the *method* `mainloop()` on the singular screen instance.  By default, turtle exposes both an *object-oriented* interface and a *functional* interface.  I advocate importing turtle via `from turtle import Screen, Turtle` to disable the functional interface to avoid common confusions that arise from mixing the two.

Answer (score 0):

An object is sort of like a blueprint for a code-like thing. When the author of the book does

```
bob = turtle.Turtle()
```

They are "instantiating" (or creating) a specific version of the Turtle object, which you will refer to as bob. Bob has certain methods you can call on it, which all turtle objects have, but when you do something like.

```
bob.forward(100)
```

It will move your specific turtle forward by 100 units.

Comment: Thank you! So i'm not understanding better! :) So basically Turtle() is a function in the turtle module? Is it an ordinary function like def Turtle(): print ("hi") ? Obviously with different body

Comment: Sort of - you'll get to "classes" in your python book which will help you understand it better, but basically Turtle is an object, and you can create a turtle by doing: 
    x = Turtle()

This isn't a function called turtle, but something that tells the Turtle object to create one of itself (called an init function).

Comment: More likely, `Turtle` is a *class* in the `turtle.py` module

Comment: So i'm creating an object of the class Turtle and so i can then acess all methods and variables inside of the Turtle class?